# Hibernate Groovy entities

Tags: hibernate, exception, groovy, casting

I'm have a groovy hibernate entity, named 'Depart' for example.
Now when i'm try to get their property (for example Long id = somedepart.getIdDepart() ) i'm got an exception

```
Cannot cast Depart to Depart_$$_javassist_5
```

Who make Depart_$$_javassist_5 - groovy or hibernate? Is there some workaround about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After about three weeks i'm found root of problem... But still can't uderstand it. Problem solved by clearing tomcat work directory, i'm this some cached classes was there.